# Имя-фамилия в названии населенных пунктов

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика

Есть такие населенные пункты, которые названы в честь каких-либо известных людей. Например, насколько я знаю, есть Лев Толстой.
По идее, подобное название должны писаться так же, как и имя-фамилия - с большой буквы и без дефиса. Однако словарь Лопатина утверждает, что между ними должен ставиться дефис: Лев-Толстой.
Кому верить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Дело не в том, кому верить, а кому - нет. **Это новая тенденция в русском языке. Орфографическая комиссия утверждает, что правила 1956 года устаревают, т.е. в некоторых случаях не соответствуют практике письма**. Такое написание предлагается, чтобы отличать географическое название от имени писателя. Сегодня орфографические словари фиксируют: Лев-Толстой (станция и поселок). См., например: Лопатин В. В., Нечаева И. В., Чельцова Л. К. Прописная или строчная? Орфографический словарь. М., 2011*

> Хотя не пойму объяснения: "не соответствуют практике письма". Что же не соответствует? Не соответствовать может тогда, когда тот или иной вариант (новый) распространяется достаточно широко, что практически становится единственно верным; второй, старый устаревает. В написание же через дефис собственных имен совпадающих с географическими названиями мне лично никогда не встречалось. И вряд ли, на мой взгляд, тут можно что-то спутать: подобные географические названия обычно сопровождаются родовыми названиями: поселок Лев-Толстой, станция Лев-Толстой. Но и старый вариант, мне кажется, нельзя считать ошибкой.

Comment: Лев-Толстовский район (Липецкая область) без дефиса не смотрится.